# openmp parallel for over struct members?

Tags: gcc, struct, parallel-processing, openmp

Is it possible to parallelize loop over stuct members with OpenMP?
I tried the following with GCC

```
point_t p;
double sum;
#pragma omp parallel for private(p) reduction(+: sum)
for (p.x = 0; p.x < N; p.x++) {
    for (p.y = 0; p.y < N; p.y++) {
            sum += foo(p);
    }
}
```

But that gives me a compile error

```
    error: expected iteration declaration or initialization before ‘p
```

Is this a GCC bug or is it not part of the OpenMP specs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is allowed in OpenMP; `parallel for` needs to loop over a *variable*, not a general lvalue. Do

```
int x, y;  // or whatever you store in a point_t
double sum;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
for (x=0; x<N; x++)
    for (y=0; y<N; y++) {
        point_t p(x, y);  // assuming C++
        sum += foo(p);
    }
```